# What are some viable chemicals that can replace melanin?

Tags: biology, humans, aliens, biochemistry

I am looking for a way to make humans to have blue, green, and other skin colors, if chemically possible.
I need chemicals that can replace eumelanin (Brown/Dark skin color) and pheomelanin (Pinkish/Yellowish skin color). Those chemicals should be able to perform the same functions melanin have like protect from UV radiation and so on.

Anyone has any idea of chemicals that could replace melanin on human skin and that could come from the same precursors (dopaquinone, basically)?